# The vite profile does not take effect at all

Tags: vue.js, vite

###### vite.config.js

```
export default {
    root:'./',
    server: {
        host: '0.0.0.0',
        port: 8080,
        open: true,
        proxy: {
            '/dev': 'http://localhost:6806'
        }
    }
}
```

I am a green hand. After `npm run dev`, the server is still running on the 3000, and the request on the developer tools is:
`POST http://localhost:3000/dev/api/query/sql 404 (Not Found)`
The true result should be  localhost:6806, right?

```
//package.json
...
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite",
    "build": "vite build"
  },
...
```

Both files are in the root directory

Answer (score 1):

My Vite version is 1.x

But the document that I read is for Vite 2.0.

Just upgrade Vite.

Comment: You can accept your own answer then:)